# How to feed env variables from an outside source to react js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, environment-variables

```
.
├── backend
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── routes
│   └── server.js
├── frontend
│   ├── node_modules
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── public
│   └── src
├── config
│   ├── .env
```

Above is my project structure. I have 3 folders, frontend, backend and the config folder. I have my .env file inside my config folder. What i want is to read the variables from the env file inside the config folder using `react js` which is the frontend

Comment: For react js to recognize your environment variables you need to define them in the react app's root folder and start their names with `REACT_APP_`, check [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/) for reference.
You might have to create another `.env` in the `frontend` directory. [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64977509/20769551) for more info

Comment: what have you tried so far ??

Comment: is there any way to feed env variables from external sources to react app?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow those steps:

1. Provide a variable in your .env file which start with `REACT_APP_` (e.g: `REACT_APP_MY_VAR`)
2. Then, in your code, you can get it using `process.env` (e.g: `process.env.REACT_APP_MY_VAR`)

Example:

Define the variables in `.env` file

```
REACT_APP_COUNT=0
REACT_APP_DOMAIN_NAME=stackoverflow
```

How to use?

```
console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_DOMAIN_NAME);

// output: stackoverflow
```

Don't forget to restart the application when you add a new environment variable.